# Apple magic keyboard not working on Windows 10 PC

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, mouse

I have bought the new Apple Magic keyboard for my pc. I tried following lots of links on how to make it work on my PC but none of which really work.

For example, I open windows Bluetooth device and they informed me of the following

[image]

I then press this pin on my apple keyboard and press enter as everyone says but it did not work.

I have not installed any drivers as it was not advised to do so.

NB: when I connect this keyboard with the cable to my pc everything works perfectly.

Please, may someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have searched for

https://magicutilities.net/magic-keyboard/download

whereby I have downloaded a copy of the keyboard and you have to install it. Then go to your Bluetooth settings and connect to the keyboard even if it does not respond to your pin.

So

1. Go to this website and download the software for the keyboard and install it
2. Redo the Bluetooth connection
3. press the pin
4. even if it does not respond press connect

This has worked for me.

Comment: Yes, but that software is not free, not a lot of money, 14 euros e ery year. Well it is not a lot, yes it is not Office 365, retouching a driver file does not deserve that much.

Comment: Okay, so I also tried to connect the Apple Magic Keyboard to Windows 10 and I ran into several problems. 1. As long as I had it connected via USB, it couldn't be discovered by Windows 2. Even when pairing was then initialized, Windows showed a driver problem So I unplugged the keyboard and installed the mentioned Magic Utilities. Then the pairing worked fine. I didn't have to enter any sort of PIN on the keyboard, but simply confirmed that this was the right device. I am writing this via bluetooth now :) Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4):

Just found the solution here: https://gist.github.com/mcandre/a1c6915d2e338fef6a42e54655d28062

- Go to "Add Bluetooth or other device"
- Find the wireless keyboard and hit connect.
- When prompted for a pin, enter anything on the screen, I used "123123". I dont know what else will work.
  NOW IS THE IMPORTANT PART.
- HIT 'Connect' and IMMEDIATELY enter '123123'+ENTER on the wireless apple keyboard, and you should be paired. '
- If you have issues, turn off bluetooth and restart the wireless keyboard and repeat the process.

Comment: I was burned on this process until I found this answer. The third and fourth points are crucial.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the https://gist.github.com/mcandre/a1c6915d2e338fef6a42e54655d28062:

1. The PIN can be anything you want. We tried 123123
2. You need to type the PIN on **both** keyboards. First, enter a PIN into the built-in/wired keyboard. Then, enter the PIN into your Apple wireless keyboard. Be prepared for it not to connect, but don't give up.

Answer (score 0):

I have the Magic Keyboard working with my Windows 10 system. Download the latest Windows Drivers from the Apple Support site ([Downloads: Windows drivers](https://support.apple.com/downloads/windows-drivers)) and you should be able to install the keyboard driver from the zip file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when I would go in Bluetooth & other devices on Windows 10 and click on Add Bluetooth or other devices, I would eventually see my Magic Keyboard with Touch ID appearing, but when I would select it, I would get an error message saying: "Try connecting your device again". What solved the issue for me, was to update my Bluetooth drivers using the ones provided by Intel here: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/18649/intel-wireless-bluetooth-for-windows-10-and-windows-11.html.