# Apple Magic Keyboard on Windows 10 (fn key and layout)

Tags: keyboard, windows

**1. How do you get the Apple Magic keyboard to work on Windows 10 with the <kbd>fn</kbd> key and the correct layout?**

I'm using a Magic Keyboard with British English layout but none of the <kbd>fn</kbd> functions work such as media keys, volume, <kbd>Page Up</kbd>, <kbd>Page Down</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Del</kbd>, etc.

What I have tried:

- Using https://github.com/uxsoft/AppleWirelessKeyboard.  I can't get this to work on Windows 10 (even using the  5.1.5640 drivers). I'm even using the recommended version of the drivers as per [this comments](https://github.com/uxsoft/AppleWirelessKeyboard/issues/7#issuecomment-352849856).
- [Various other versions of the Apple Windows 64-bit drivers](https://superuser.com/a/608904/406840) (none of them make a difference)
- Using Boot Camp on Windows (doesn't do anything)
- [using uawks](https://superuser.com/a/2950/406840) (doesn't seem to have been updated since 2008). It doesn't work with <kbd>fn</kbd> functions and seems to cause the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to be permanently depressed.

**2. How do you get the Apple Magic keyboard to work on Windows 10 with the correct layout?**

I've also not had any luck using the <kbd><sup>|</sup> \</kbd> key (it works as a <kbd><sup>~</sup> #</kbd> instead) the <kbd><sup>~</sup> `</kbd> key (it works as a <kbd><sup>¬</sup> `</kbd> instead) and the <kbd><sup>±</sup> §</kbd> key (it works as a <kbd><sup>|</sup> \</kbd> instead)

I'm using  Windows 10 Version 10.0.18362 Build 18632.

Comment: Apple’s “British “ keyboard is kind of unique, you probably need to find a Windows layout called “British (Apple)” to have output match the keys.

Comment: But won't that mess up my other keyboards?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding 2., the mapping for the keys that create characters, you probably need a Windows software keyboard layout that matches Apple's unique "British" hardware keyboard.   See if [this one](http://www.logikdev.com/2010/02/18/apple-uk-keyboard-layout-for-windows/) works right for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use this: https://magicutilities.net/magic-keyboard/help/keyboard-layouts
DON'T install the main program from their website that's a paid for app - this just installs the right keyboard layout for British Apple Keyboards. You then go into Windows 10 keyboard settings and add United Kingdom (Magic Utilities) as the default input method and voila ALL the keys work like they do on a mac! The only thing that doesn't seem to work is the brightness/volume buttons up the top (but I think bootcamp drivers can fix that if you must).
No need to install any third party drivers for any of this just plug in, install the keyboard map and go!

Comment: Very useful, great find!

Comment: Unfortunately (even though the instructions are not correct for Windows 10) after installing and restarting the languages do not appear in the menu so it's impossible to activate this.

Comment: I ended up buying the main utility program https://magicutilities.net/ is it fantastic and worked right out of box

Comment: I can confirm that the magicutilities.net program restores the Fn functionality right out of the box with a driver install. This is a smooth user experience.

Answer (score 2):

I have built a little open source project for this: Bluetooth HID Hub (https://github.com/ruundii/bthidhub).  It runs on Raspberry Pi Zero W (~$10/£10).

It is similar to RaspiKey, but:

Supports not only a keyboard, but a mouse as well, both wired or wireless
Does not require wire connection to your computer
Supports connection to multiple computers (work on 2+ machines with the same keyboard
Python based, so really easy to extend with your custom remappings or any other device specific logic

Comment: Yikes. It’s a cool project, but Bluetooth latency is already terrible and this will make things even worse

Answer (score 2):

Just for apple keyboard mapping based on macbook pro. please see my article.
Will most likely work for other mac keyboards.
[Apple Keyboard Layout on Windows 10 PC. Not via bootcamp [How to]](https://www.getcoding.co.uk/apple-mac-keyboard-layout-on-windows-10-pc/)

Summary:
use Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator (MSKLC) Version 1.4.
create layout template and install.
ready made template available via link above on own website.

a piece of software called Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator (MSKLC) Version 1.4. can be used to create keyboard layouts.

The main key that was missing from the layout was the hashtag symbol. After adding this key into the layout on the correct place on the 3 key, being able to be accessed using right alt + 3 keys.

then you can install the new layout file into windows and the issue should be fixed

Comment: It would be helpful for anyone that comes across this in the future if you could [edit] in a summary of the article. Links become broken or servers stop working, so a summary could still help future readers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the article is part of my own personal website that i created, manage and host. Thanks for your point.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWgWJ9BcCUo This saved me. If you are still struggling from this, then this is a quick answer.

Comment: (The video link purportedly shows how to set up Autohotkey to set up keyboard shortcuts to adjust the volume.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an Apple Magic Keyboard with Windows 11. The Keyboard Manager from [Microsoft PowerToys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) worked great for me. Source here: [How to Use a Mac Magic Keyboard on a Windows PC](https://www.lifewire.com/use-magic-keyboard-on-windows-pc-5197318)

Comment: PowerToys fails to detect the fn key (at least here)

Answer (score 0):

> **1. How do you get the Apple Magic keyboard to work on Windows 10 with the fn key and the correct layout?**

I managed to get the Fn key to work by downloading Boot Camp files from Apple that come with installers for Windows. [This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXf75lUuqWM) guided me there. It also explains switching the default behavior for F1-12 keys (Fn active or not) via the Windows Registry.

Note that the script from Github used in the video is not necessary. The description of the video has a link directly to the Boot Camp files. Furthermore, other users gave useful hints in the comments.