# Erratic keyboard function on Dell laptop (Windows 10) -when paired with bluetooth Magic Keyboard

Tags: bootcamp, magic-keyboard-ipad

I have a Dell Precision laptop that is running Windows 10 Enterprise. I recently bought a bluetooth Magic Keyboard (Apple) that is giving me intermittent issues when I connect it to my Dell laptop (via Bluetooth). It works fine for 10-20 min and then suddenly the keys start repeating erratically and on their own . I then have to end up rebooting my laptop - and then everything works fine for 20 min - and then the same thing happens.

I believe I may need to download the latest drivers to address this compatibility issue ?

Also please note - I have connected a Dell 4K monitor to my laptop (so I have 2 screens). I doubt if having 2 screens is creating the problem.

Comment: Ask Different is for Apple equipment, for Dell please try a different stack.

Comment: @SolarMike The Magic Keyboard ***is*** Apple equipment, isn't it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apple magic keyboard not working on Windows 10 PC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328527/apple-magic-keyboard-not-working-on-windows-10-pc)